# Minimum space between last word and page number in the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, page-numbering

y question is, whether there is a solution to define a minimum blank space (length: three dots) between an entry's last word and the its page number within the table of contents?

Thanks a lot!

Update [08.01.2014]:

Hi! I have tried your solution, but interestingly, the space is connected to the page number's length. Thus the dots were removed if the page number increases (see my example).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberbox}{\hspace*{3em}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter}
some text
\section{section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{10}
\section{Another section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{100}
\section{Next section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1000}
\section{Guess! It's a section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{10000}
\section{Finally, the last section}
some text
\end{document}
```

This code result in the tiff-file below. How can I fix this problem?

[image: Output]

Comment: What class are you using, and are you loading any packages that allow you to modify the table of contents?  A minimum working example is nearly always very helpful, and shortens the amount of time it takes for you to receive a helpful and accurate answer.

Comment: The titletoc package has a \contentsmargin command that lets you choose the rightmargin for the entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since in your older questions you've always used the `scrbook` class, I'll assume that you are using it.

To make modifications to the ToC in KOMA classes usually the package `tocstyle` is used.

If you want to keep the normal ToC of KOMA classes use

```
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
```

and to achieve what you want use the line

```
\settocstylefeature[1]{pagenumberbox}{\hspace*{3em}}
```

Note that approximately each `em` corresponds to a dot you want to remove.

Also note that the optional argument `[1]` sets this behavior for `\section`s only (2 is for `\subsection`s, etc.). If you want it for all sectioning commands, simply remove it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\settocstylefeature[1]{pagenumberbox}{\hspace*{3em}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter}
some text
\section{section}
some text
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

To obtain what you have described in your edited question, it is better to resort to the `titletoc` package, issuing the command

```
\contentsmargin{3em}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{3em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter}
some text
\section{section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{10}
\section{Another section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{100}
\section{Next section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1000}
\section{Guess! It's a section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{10000}
\section{Finally, the last section}
some text
\end{document}
```

or, without any additional package, redefine the command `\@pnumwidth` to be

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter}
some text
\section{section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{10}
\section{Another section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{100}
\section{Next section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1000}
\section{Guess! It's a section}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{10000}
\section{Finally, the last section}
some text
\end{document}
```

In both cases the output is:

[image]

Comment: I have tried your solution. Unfortunately, your suggestions result in another problem (please read my update above). Perhaps you can also solve this second problem?

Comment: @Friedrich I know, I intended to be like that, but I misunderstood you. In the edited answer how to achieve what you want.